# Tables and plots of output effects of government spending shocks from lpirfs package in R?

Tags: plot, panel, r-package

I am using the lpirfs package to estimate the output effects of a positive government spending shock.
I'm not very familiar with this package, except for the function itself.
I have estimate a linear model using the function lp_lin_panel.
My objective is to:

1. Customize the plot of my estimation.
2. Extract a table with the output values corresponding to each horizon. For reference, I need to extract a table similar to Table 2 in Yoshino, Miyamoto (2020).

As for the first point, I tried using ggplot2 and ggplotify to customize the plot. However, both require a dataframe and apparently my estimations cannot be converted into a dataframe.
I faced the same problem for the second point.

Thank you to anyone who's willing to help!